# Can I create a selector file using the Plastic command line utility?

Tags: plasticscm

I am attempting to write a batch file for my developers to run that sets up workspaces.  The batch file will use Plastic's command line utility, `cm.exe`.

When I create a workspace in the Plastic client GUI, there is a combo box that allows me to select the  repository.  This generates a `plastic.workspace` file, and a `plastic.selector` file that contains a reference to the selected repository.

However, when I use the command line utlity to make a workspace, I have to specify an existing selector:

`cm mkwk MyWorkspace c:\MyWorkspacePath --selector=my.selector`

or edit the selector when prompted:

`cm mkwk MyWorkspace c:\MyWorkspacePath --selector`

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like

`cm mkwk MyWorkspace c:\MyWorkspacePath MyRepository@MyServer:8888`

and have the files generated the same way that they are done by the GUI.

Is there a way to do this using `cm.exe`, or do I have to write all the selectors beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not documented, you can issue the "mkwk" command with the "--repository" parameter. For example:

```
cm mkwk code c:\code --repository=code@localhost:8087
```

Hope it helps!